# What is the easiest way to detect if an Android Wear device is connected to the phone?

Tags: android, wear-os

I want my app to behave differently if an Android Wear device is currently connected. What is the easiest way to detect this?

I believe that you could use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.html#getConnectedNodes%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29) which is in Google Play Services, but that seems like a lot of overhead just to see if the device is there or not. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

NodeAPI can check whether your Android Wear device and phone are connected or not in a simple way like this:

This is the callback function when you call:

```
private void checkNodeAPI(){
    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(this, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

//Callback

```
@Override
public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
    if (getConnectedNodesResult != null && getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes() != null){
        mWearableConnected = false;
        for (Node node : getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes()){
            if (node.isNearby()){
                mWearableConnected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    Log.v("TEST", "mWearableConnected: " + mWearableConnected);
}
```

getConnectedNodes() is an async function, so the result is just returned after a while, you can not get it immediately.

To receive the event when an Android Wear connects/disconnects to your phone, you can use this below function to add listener:

```
Wearable.NodeApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);

@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
    Log.v("TEST", "onPeerConnected");
    mWearableConnected = true;
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
    Log.v("TEST", "onPeerDisconnected");
    checkNodeAPI();
}
```

But this listener is not always called on some Android Wear devices.

Comment: There is also a sync-function: Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient).await()

Answer (score 1):

You must use [`Wearable.NodesApi.getConnnectedNodes()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.html#getConnectedNodes%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29) API, as you state.

There is no other method to do this, at least currently.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a boolean value (say mIsConnected) that is set to true in onPeerConnected and false in onPeerDisconnected.

If you are using a [WearableListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html), these methods will automatically be included and you just have to override them: onPeerConnected(Node peer) and onPeerDisconnected(Node peer). If you want to do this in an Activity or something instead, just implement [NodeApi.NodeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.NodeListener.html), which has those methods. Make sure to add it to your Google API client ([addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.html#addListener(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi.NodeListener))).

Comment: Here is problem: onPeerConnected() or onPeerDisconnected() is called if "connect occured" or "disconnect occured". But onPeerConnected() won't called if phone connected to watch before application started. And onPeerDisconnected() won't called if phone disconnected from watch before application started. So, seems to be Wearable.NodesApi.getConnnectedNodes() is only way to "ask" service about connected nodes.

Comment: I have tested NodeListener (onPeerConnected and onPeerDisconnected ) on both emulator and real device (Zen Watch 2). While these functions were called on emulator each time Android Wear connect/disconnect, it didn't happen on Zen Watch 2. I don't know why, but I think emulator has latest Google Play Service, but Zen Watch 2 doesn't.